# Trying to do something if value isn't equal in foreach loop, but not getting expected results

Tags: php, loops, recursion, foreach

I have a database that looks like this:

[image]

I can generate a tree from this menu using the following code:

```
foreach($categories->result_array() as $category):
    $menu_array[$category['id']] = array('name' => $category['name'], 'parent' => $category['parent'], 'id' => $category['id']);
endforeach;

echo '<ul>';
echo $this->tasks->generateCategoriesTree(NULL, $menu_array);
echo '</ul>';
```

And here's the function the above code calls:

```
function generateCategoriesTree($parent, $menu_array, $result = NULL)
{
    foreach($menu_array as $key => $value):
        if ($value['parent'] == $parent):
            $result .= '<li>';
            $result .= '<a href="#">' . $value['name'] . '</a>';
            $result .= '<ul>';
            $result .= $this->generateCategoriesTree($key, $menu_array);
            $result .= '</li></ul>';
          endif;
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}
```

It generates a tree that looks like this:

[image]

My problem now is getting the parent category to be bold. In my database, row's that are parents have the parent column as `NULL`. I've tried a couple things, such as a `if ($value['parent'] !== $parent)` then applying a bold style, but that doesn't work. I honestly cannot wrap my head around this. I would appreciate any help you guys can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make it bold if the parent is equal to NULL.  I'm not sure about the use of the syntax since I normally use parentheses for if-structures.

```
function generateCategoriesTree($parent, $menu_array, $result = NULL)
{
    foreach($menu_array as $key => $value):
        if ($value['parent'] == $parent):
            $result .= '<li>';
            if($value['parent'] == NULL):
                $result .= '<a class="BOLDCLASS" href="#">' . $value['name'] . '</a>';
            else:
                $result .= '<a href="#">' . $value['name'] . '</a>';
            endif;  
            $result .= '<ul>';
            $result .= $this->generateCategoriesTree($key, $menu_array);
            $result .= '</li></ul>';
          endif;
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}
```

You would have to use some styling to make the class **BOLDCLASS** bold of course.

Comment: Weird, I swear I tried this. But then I realized I added in a if ($value['parent'] == $parent): right after the if($value['parent'] == NULL): statement. But yes, this works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Swap the parameters in the `generateCategoriesTree` function declaration so that `$menu_array` comes before `$parent`. So:

```
function generateCategoriesTree($menu_array, $parent = 0, $result = null) { ... }
```

Remember to change the parameter order in your `generateCategoriesTree` function calls too...

In your calling function:

```
echo $this->tasks->generateCategoriesTree($menu_array);
```

And in `generateCategoriesTree` itself:

```
$result .= $this->generateCategoriesTree($menu_array, $key);
```

Then simply test if `$parent == 0` and apply bold style.

Answer (score 0):

For the top level, have you tried this?

```
if ($value['parent'] !== '')
```

Then you can use the OR operator once you have that level solved.

Comment: Shouldn't the value be equal to '' for it to be a toplevel?

Comment: I tried this but all it bolds the parents AND runs through the loop so it results in duplicate categories: http://snipt.org/uiKb4 http://i.imgur.com/5hJdb.png

Comment: I think the way I would handle this situation is to generate another array or string that holds the IDs of the parent items, then when the parent item in the tree construction loop matches an array or string item set the CSS to make the text bold.